# How Can I Add Multiple Network Card to a VM on Azure?

Tags: azure, ubuntu, networking, routes

I have a test server(ubuntu 16.04 xenial) on azure.I want to bind multiple network card this vm.I can bind network cards from azure portal.In the vm i can see (ip a) that network card and ip.When i try to reach internet via first network card (eth0) it is succesful.But when i try with this:

> ping 8.8.8.8 -I eth1

It can not reach internet.

In the documentation it says add static route for you vm.I tried with following command but result is same:

> ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1 metric 10

Also i can not add route without metric
Here are my default route table:

```
root@test:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
168.63.129.16   192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

root@test:~# ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
root@test:~# ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1 metric 10
root@test:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    10     0        0 eth1
168.63.129.16   192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
root@test:~# ping 8.8.8.8 -I eth0
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.0.4 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=2.51 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=2.10 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.102/2.308/2.514/0.206 ms
root@test:~# ping 8.8.8.8 -I eth1
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.1.4 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
18 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 17410ms
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access public network from your second NIC , try the command below :

```
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1 table 11
ip rule add from 192.168.1.4 table 11
```

*11 is just an identifier here , if you add third NIC, you can add its route to table 12 ,13....*

With this done , you should use your second NIC private IP to ping public network address:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -I 192.168.1.4
```

Hope it helps .

Comment: Hi @akuscu , how's going ? Has your issue been solved ?

Comment: Thanks for answer.But actually i want to be able to use both of my NICs.I think in this solution it only allow to use 2. nic.

Comment: This still does not work, according to my test on Azure. I suspect Azure blocks the ICMP traffic from the second NIC?